# streamlit " error is not recognized as cmdlet name"

Tags: python, streamlit, anaconda3, python-webbrowser

am trying to build a streamlit web app i have installed streamlit in my anaconda environment with the command :

```
conda create --name streamlit_env python=3.10 
conda activate streamlit_env
pip install streamlit
```

when i try `conda list` that show streamlit is installed but when i try to run a python file in vscode with `streamlit run xxx` (through my streamlit_env environment set as interpreter) i get the error below

```
streamlit: The term "streamlit" is not recognized as a cmdlet name, function, script file, or program 
executable. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path exists, verify that the path is correct and try again.
To the character Line:1 : 1
+ streamlit run initiation.py
+ ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (streamlit:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

i tried to reinstall streamlit doesn't worked

Comment: Is the bin directory for your virtual environment on your PATH? I'm not familiar with `streamlit`, but `python3 -m streamlit` may work if it exposes itself as an executable module

Comment: @Brian61354270
 you mean this directory `C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\Library\bin` ? if so yes i added it in my PATH otherwise please which bin directory you talking?

Comment: No, I mean the bin directory for the virtual environment `streamlit_env`, which is where pip is going to install scripts/executables for any installed packages. It's usually `$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin` on unix systems, but conda may do things weirdly on Windows

Comment: Typically "activating" your virtual enviroment means prepending the virutal envs bin directory your PATH. Not sure why it isn't working here. Are you working from the same shell/terminal that you ran `conda activate streamlit_env` in?

Comment: @Brian61354270
instead of running `streamlit run` in vscode i tried in my anaconda powershell where i installed streamlit like you suggested. that returned the following error  `File "C:\Users\ryan\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\pyarrow\__init__.py", line 65, in <module>
    import pyarrow.lib as _lib
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing lib: La procédure spécifiée est introuvable.` i coudn't show all the error message so this is the end, please can you help ?